# How do you hide and show specific menu items based on a set cookie in 1.9

Tags: menu, navigation

First off I have found this site SUPER helpful in the past dozen years for my days working with Oscommerce and now with Magento. So thanks to all the contributors to stackexchange.  I am only 6 months in with Magento now and want to do things the right way and not code around the features and proper methods in Magento.

Ok, so I know how to set a cookie for what I am doing I just need to know the best way to change a menu button.  Basically I am trying to accomplish the following.

Show a menu item which I currently have that says "Select Vehicle" and once selected I have it set a cookie already.  Here is the part I need help with. I would like to then have that same menu item show up as "Shop Now".   I think the best way is to make both buttons and have them do what I want them to do and then make one visable and the other not visable based on the cookie set?  Or is there a better way.  So far I have conformed to Magento by only messing with my theme and by adding CMS blocks and what not.  Obviously I could "hard code" this but I know this is bad in case of a future migration.  So yeah help me with ideas and approaches please to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still digging around on my own on this with no luck. Anyone?

Comment: Any ideas on this?  I still haven't found this exact solution but I got the site up and live and working well with a different approach.